# Opening frequently used software using terminal with user assigned short names in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, shortcut-keys

I recently installed Ubuntu and I want to make the desktop to a minimum. I am planning to remove the dock and use the terminal instead to open up the software I use. Some software I use have long names, So I am trying to assign new short names to them so I can use that in the terminal to open them. For example I am using stm32cube ide. I just want to open that software by just using something like following,

```
cube
```

I want to do the same thing to couple of other software as well. How do I achieve this? So far I have seen a method that involves editing /bin folder and including a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Edit by typing `i`, add `alias cube='<your command>'` at the bottom, then leave by typing `:wq`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Your changes will take effect when starting a new *session*, or you may activate them by sourcing .bashrc